# Error al inicializar clase de una librería estática c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Desde ya hace un tiempo tengo un problema con un proyecto que tengo que implementar en el mio, os lo explico.

Mi objetivo es llamar a una clase de C++ desde una aplicación C# (**Proyecto 1**), el problema es que dicho proyecto C++ (**Proyecto 3**) no es compatible con **CLR**.

Lo que he hecho hasta ahora ha sido crear un proyecto intermedio también en **Unmanaged C++** (**Proyecto 2**) para que sea compatible con el proyecto 3.

El proyecto 2 consiste básicamente en un método muy simple que inicializa una clase del proyecto 3 y usa este objeto para diferentes operaciones.

Estoy trabajando en Visual Studio y este no me da ningún error a la hora de compilar, pero en tiempo de ejecución me sale el siguiente error:

> No se puede cargar el archivo DLL 'RUTA-PROYECTO\Proyecto2.dll': No se
>   encontró el proceso especificado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
>   en proyecto1.procesar()

La cosa es que el anterior error me sale solo cuando dentro del método del proyecto2 inicializo la clase del proyecto 3, si comento la linea de inicialización entoces me va bien, no logro entender por que entre 2 proyectos de c++ del mismo tipo me da este tipo de problemas.

Alguien se el ocurre como puedo ver que esta fallando o que puede estar fallando?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ese error no suele ser muy ambiguo. Por algún motivo no consigue encontrar la dll Proyecto2.dll o en algunos casos una función dentro de ella, aunque esto último es muy descartable. Mueve Proyecto.dll a los directorios de entorno, en Windows uno general es la carpeta system32 y windows y haz la llamada sin RUTA-PROYECTO. Recuerda que también podría ser una dependencia de Proyecto2.dll,osea otra dll llamada desde Proyecto2.dll.